# Does Cartthrob + Stripe only accepts dollars?

Tags: cartthrob, stripe

I have cartthrob and stripe set up and throughout the cart process everything says euros, the admin panel, to invoice, the order confirmation, etc. The default currency setting in Cartthrob is set to EUR as well.

When I send to stripe, it always accepts payment in dollars then converts to euro. My default currency in stripe is set to EUR, but my location is always being set as purchasing from the US in my stripe test area.

The question is, how do I allow stripe/cartthrob to make sure euro is sent as the primary currency and how do I change the default country the payment comes from?

Comment: It sounds like CartThrob is fine, but you probably have a setting in your account with Stripe that is set as defaulting or forcing to US currency. I would check there and also contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the cartthrob / stripe payment plugin has dollars hard-coded into it by default. Changing that solves the problem...

Comment: If it's a free and open source plugin, I recommend throwing a pull request with your fix, for the good of the community. If it's paid for, make your suggested edits directly to the author and hope they care.